# Is it possible to use a joystick with vhdl?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, joystick, adc

I’m pretty new to coding with vhdl and i just finished making a simple game using a pretty rough vga driver that i made. The last thing now that i need to do is hook up a joystick to be able to control the object in the game( this game is a mini project so i have to present it and using the onboard switches wouldn’t cut it). The problem is that the joystick gives an analog input and i don’t know how to include that in my vhdl program or if its even possible. I’m using a de-10 lite board. I’m sorry if my question is messy and i hope I made it clear for you. Thx in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" - electronics.

Answer (score 1):

DE10-Lite is built with MAX 10 fpga which has two on-chip ADCs, and the board has analog buffers to scale 5v analog inputs down to acceptable voltage of 2.5v.

You'll need to instantiate "Modular ADC core" and PLL to clock it.

Depending on your project needs you can instantiate just the ADC control core (it has simple streaming interface), or "standard sequencer with avalon-mm sample storage".

Check with the board's manuals to find which pins are connected to banks with ADC.

Apparently, there's an example project for ADC included with "CD-ROM" that you can download from Terasic site.

Comment: I have looked into your suggestion of using the adc control core bu unfortunately I didn’t manage to make it work. As I’ve mentioned before I’m quite new to this and i haven't been able to get an output that i can work with using the adc.I have taken a good look at the generated code and i don't understand most of it to be honest. Would you mind explaining it in a bit more detail?

Comment: @EslamAllam did you looked into ADC_RTL project from the "Demonstrations" subdirectory of a DE10-Lite_v.2.0.3_SystemCD.zip? There's an extremely simple design. Just the adc core, hardcoded for continuous sampling, with channel selectable with onboard switches, and outputs to 7-seg static display. It's provided for your exact board, so you can run and test it before tinkering.